# Which Quadric Surface Is $-9x'^2+3y'^2+6z'^2=1$

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

> Classify the quadric surface
>
> $$3x^2-2y^2-z^2-4xy-12yz-8xz=1$$

I have found the eigenvalues which are $-9,6,3$

So it is $$-9x'^2+3y'^2+6z'^2=1$$

According to a page I have $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ is an elliptic hyperboloid of one sheet and $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=-1$ is an elliptic hyperboloid of two sheets.

So which is $3x^2-2y^2-z^2-4xy-12yz-8xz=1$?

Comment: The key feature to look at is the number of plus and minus signs in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $-9x'^2+3y'^2+6z'^2=1$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{X^2}{(1/\sqrt{6})^2}+\frac{Y^2}{(1/\sqrt{3})^2}-\frac{Z^2}{(1/3)^2}=1$$
where $X=z'$, $Y=y'$ and $Z=x'$ (we swapped $x'$-axis and $z'$-axis).
So it is a [one-sheet elliptic hyperboloid](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E2%E2%88%922y%5E2%E2%88%92z%5E2%E2%88%924xy%E2%88%9212yz%E2%88%928xz%3D1).

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the quadratic form is $(2,1)$, hence this quadric is a `one-sheet hyperboloid`.